# KSH Resolving Environmental Variables for an Entire File

Tags: environment-variables, output, ksh

I have a list of file names with environment variables in them.  I'd like to read the file line by line and then set a variable to the read in line however have the envirnment variable translated to the appropriate environment variable. Here is my script so far:

```
#!/bin/ksh

. /test/currentEnv.sh

while read line
do
        echo $line
done < $1
```

if my source file is:

```
foo1$ENVVAR1.csv 
foo2$ENVVAR2.csv
foo3$ENVVAR3.csv
```

and my Environment variables in currentEnv.sh are

```
$ENVVAR1=hello;     export ENVVAR1     
$ENVVAR2=world;     export ENVVAR2
$ENVVAR3=test;      export ENVVAR3
```

I'd like the results of the script to be

```
foo1hello.csv
foo2world.csv
foo3test.csv
```

currently it just dumps out the original file:

```
foo1$ENVVAR1.csv 
foo2$ENVVAR2.csv
foo3$ENVVAR3.csv
```

Edit

I was able to get the majority of my files resolved using:
    #!/bin/ksh

```
. /test/currentEnv.sh

while read line
do
        eval echo $line
done < $1
```

however some of my variables are in the middle of string like:

```
foo3$ENVVAR3_bar.csv
```

this seems to look for an env variable $ENVVAR3_bar and doesn't find it I need this to output:

```
foo3test_bar.csv
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You declare a variable *without* the dollar sign:

   ```
   $var=value     # no
   var=value      # yes
   ```
2. Since underscore is a valid character for a variable name, ksh is trying to expand the variable named `ENVVAR3_bar`: you need to use braces to separate the variable name from the surrounding text:

   ```
   foo3$ENVVAR3_bar.csv      # no
   foo3${ENVVAR3}_bar.csv    # yes
   ```

Comment: Yep, the curly brackets did it.  I do declare the variables without the $, just typed it wrong. Thanks for the input.